# How to move Magento core modules from app/code to vender folder?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, vendor

I have upgraded Magento version from 2.2.7 to 2.3.2 without using composer.
I have installed new 2.3.2 from github and moved features from 2.2.7 to 2.3.2.
And now I need commit it to live server.
But in my local server, the core modules are in app/code folder, not in vendor folder.
How to fix this?

Comment: You can download Magento from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download.if you download from above, all module will come in vendor folder by default.

Comment: Github repo is mainly for developer purpose.

Comment: I know it. Of course as a web developer(but beginner to Magento), I have developed by Github repository, and now I need install it to live server. So I should move magento core modules to vendor folder.